# How do I set size of an element of an array in IDA Pro?

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

How do I set size of an element of an array in IDA Pro ? I'm creating a structure where I want to have array of DWORDs. But it defaults to bytes.

I have IDA Pro 6.1

Comment: You can edit struct definitions using plain C in the Local Types window (Shift-F1). Or you can undefine the array, define a single DWORD at the beginning of the array, and use the "make array" command to turn it into an array of DWORD.

Comment: Thanks! If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit `struct` and `enum` definitions using plain C in the Local Types window (<kbd>Shift-F1</kbd>). Just be careful, IDA does not apply any automatic structure padding between members, so you have to insert dummy members sometimes.

Or, in the Structures window (<kbd>Shift-F9</kbd>), you can undefine the array, define a single `DWORD` at its beginning, and use the Array... command (asterisk, <kbd>*</kbd>) to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Before you press <kbd>Shift-8</kbd> to define the array, first define the type as Dword by double tapping <kbd>d</kbd>, then the array will be of dwords not bytes.